# Como extraer los valores que no son iguales de 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, regex, programación-funcional

Tengo 2 arrays con diferente data, necesito sacar los valores que no sean iguales

```
var array1 = [
  'Consulta por datos de persona/entidad',
  'nitByNombres',
  'listContribuyentesByFecha',
  'BuscarNombreComercial',
  'listContribuyentesByNit',
  'Consulta de funcionarios',
  'Consulta de entidades donde laboro el funcionario',
  'ConsultarDpi'
];

var array2 = [
  'listContribuyentesByFecha',
  'BuscarNombreComercial',
  'listContribuyentesByNit',
  'SE_BUSQUEDA_CUI',
  'nitByNombres',
  'BuscarRazonDenominaciónSocial ',
  'findContribuyentesByFechaModificacion',
  'Consulta por datos de persona/entidad',
  'Consulta de funcionarios',
  'Consulta de entidades donde laboro el funcionario',
  'ConsultarDpi',
  'findContribuyentesByFechaAdicion'
];
```

Necesito comparar la data del array1 con el array2, y sacar los datos que no sean iguales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente haya una forma mas simple pero esto es lo que se me ocurre a estas horas

```js
var array1 = [
  'Consulta por datos de persona/entidad',
  'nitByNombres',
  'listContribuyentesByFecha',
  'BuscarNombreComercial',
  'listContribuyentesByNit',
  'Consulta de funcionarios',
  'Consulta de entidades donde laboro el funcionario',
  'ConsultarDpi'
];

var array2 = [
  'listContribuyentesByFecha',
  'BuscarNombreComercial',
  'listContribuyentesByNit',
  'SE_BUSQUEDA_CUI',
  'nitByNombres',
  'BuscarRazonDenominaciónSocial ',
  'findContribuyentesByFechaModificacion',
  'Consulta por datos de persona/entidad',
  'Consulta de funcionarios',
  'Consulta de entidades donde laboro el funcionario',
  'ConsultarDpi',
  'findContribuyentesByFechaAdicion'
];


a1 = new Set(array1)
a2 = new Set(array2)


console.log([...array2.filter(x => !a1.has(x)), ...array1.filter(x => !a2.has(x))])
```

Nótese que esto te da los datos que están en uno de los dos arrays pero no en el otro. si solo quieres los datos de array1 que no están en array2

```
    console.log(array1.filter(x => !a2.has(x)))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :) Voy a implementarlo en mi codigo para ver si me sirve